# Running JS on localhost - server js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I try to run the following script: 
In terminal I have written: **node server**, but I got an error message:

> Error: Cannot find module 'express'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:555:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:482:25)
>       at Module.require (module.js:604:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
>       at Object. (/home/jwisniowski/Desktop/PROJEKTY/UJ_API_PEP/shop-app/server.js:1:79)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)

sever.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
const fs = require('fs')
const api_endpoint = process.env.API_ENDPOINT || "http://localhost:8081/application-orchestration/v1"

fs.writeFileSync(
  __dirname + '/application-web/config/env.js',
  'var api_endpoint = "' + api_endpoint + '";'
);

app.use(express.static('./'))

app.get('/', (request, response) => {
  response.send('Hello from Express!')
})

app.listen(port, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.log('something bad happened', err)
  }

  console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`)
})
```

Comment: npm install express

Comment: can you please, read the error before posting the question? It says it's unable to find the `express` module. Meaning, you either did not install it or mistyped its name.

Answer (score 1):

make sure you have express in your package.json and do npm install.

or

npm install express -s

Comment: I have installed, updated but still the same issue **npm install -g express  
+ express@4.16.3
updated 1 package in 0.936s**

Comment: No, without -g just npm install express --save

Answer (score 0):

delete your node_modules folder, make sure that you have express in your package.json, and do npm install.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to install express globally ,

```
npm install -g express --save
```

**OR**

Install express locally to your project

```
npm install express --save
```